# Parsing the content of a 'Requests' call only shows some json data

Tags: python, json, python-requests

To start here is some code:

```
import requests
import json

url = r'http:\\some.url'


p = requests.post(url)
print p.status_code
data = json.load(p)
for entry in data:
    print entry

print data
```

The output of this program is as follows (note values are sanitized):

```
200
a
{"a":"b"}
```

Is there a way to get value "b" applied to a variable?  Since the post will always return {"a":"b"}, I don't really care what "a" is, since it is basically a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Python 2.x:

```
>>> x = {"a":"b"}
>>> x.values()
['b']
>>> x.values()[0]
'b'
```